# How to always set "www" in grailsUrl?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-controller

Config.groovy

```
grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
```

i set my grails url with `"http://www.changeme.com"`

in this.. when i type `changeme.com` its shows me a correct page, but when i am trying to login with `http://changeme.com` its redirecting me to same login page with `http://www.changeme.com` and when i logged in through this url then its redirecting me to my page..

So how i set always "www" in my URL.. if someone just type `changeme.com`

Comment: i would make a 301 redirect from changeme.com/* to www.changeme.com/*  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: This might be a server configuration and domain name problem not grails'. You should check with your host see if you can map both to the IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a filter like this..

```
 class HostFilters {

   def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            if(request.getHeader("host") =="changeme.com" )
            {
             redirect(url: "http://www.changeme.com")

            }
        }

    }
}
```